# Creating array containing ranks based on the values of another array?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, object, twitter

Basically, I have the arrays `$name`, `$followers` and `$imageurl`, and I would like to arrange the `$followers` array numerically, but also update the arrangement of `$name` and `$imageurl` accordingly.

For example, `$followers[0] = 2783848`, `$name[0] = "Rob"` and `$imageurl[0] = "http://xxx.com/image.jpeg"` where all three arrays are linked through having the same array key.

**For good measure, here's my whole code:**

```
$screennames = array(
                 0 => "LilKim",
                 1 => "NickiMinaj",
                 2 => "drakkardnoir",
                 3 => "LilTunechi",
                 4 => "kanyewest",
                 5 => "RealWizKhalifa",
                 6 => "beyonce",
                 7 => "KELLYROWLAND",
                 8 => "LupeFiasco",
                 9 => "TinieTempah",
                 10 => "50cent",
                 11 => "TRINArockstarr",
                 12 => "iamdiddy",
                 13 => "Timbaland",
                 14 => "chrisbrown"
                     );

for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
$xml[$i] = @simplexml_load_file('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=' . $screennames[$i]);
$name[$i] = $xml[$i]->name;
$followers[$i] = $xml[$i]->followers_count;
$imageurl[$i] = $xml[$i]->profile_image_url;
}
```

Any advice/answers/comments will be greatly appreciated :)!!

*I'm also not sure that this is the best way to query the Twitter API, so if anyone has any recommendations, feel free to leave them here :).*

**UPDATE:**

I think I've found a way to put this more precisely;

I have the arrays `$name`, `$followers` and `$imageurl` where each value is relative, e.g. `$name[0]` is relative to `$followers[0]` and `$imageurl[0]`. I would like to create a fourth array `$rank` which contains values `1-15` ordered based on the relative value of followers, for example:

```
$followers = array(0 => 278738, 1 => 32784, 2 => 103562, 3 => 37848); // Etc from keys 0 - 14

$rank[0] = 1;
$rank[1] = 4;
$rank[2] = 2;
$rank[3] = 3;
```

That should make a lot easier to figure out what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't matter if you preserve your keys.  For that use `asort`.  When you loop through the name array, the values will be arranged alphabetically(or however, depending on your asort params) and the indexes (the keys, the numbers) will be out of numeric order.

```
//show by name alphabetically
asort($names); //puts names in alphabetic order, while preserving key associations
foreach ($names as $key=>$value) {
    echo "$value has " . $followers[$key] . ' followers<br>';
}

//show ordered by most followers
arsort($names, SORT_NUMERIC); //puts followers in reverse numeric order, while preserving key associations
foreach ($followers as $key=>$value) {
    echo $name[$key] . ' has $value followers<br>';
}
```

**Update**

```
//Create rank array
$rank=0;
arsort($names, SORT_NUMERIC); //puts followers in reverse numeric order, while preserving key associations
foreach ($followers as $key=>$value) {
  $rank++; 
  $ranks[$rank]=$key;
}
```

Then you can loop through ranks, and display it, or do insert statements or whatever.

```
foreach ($ranks as $rank=>$key) {
   echo "{$name[$key]} has rank $rank";
   $sql="INSERT INTO ranks ('username','followers','rank') VALUES ('{$name['$key']}','{$followers['$key']}','$rank')";
}
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but doesn't that output "Rob has 829389 followers" for example?

Comment: It should yah. Is that not what you wanted? It would work the same if you did asort on the followers column, and looped through it, if you were wanting to show the ones with the most followers.

Comment: Thanks for your input :). I realize my question wasn't all too well laid out, and I've updated it as such. What I was really looking for was to build a fourth array with the values of ranks `1-15` based on the values of `$followers`.

Comment: Hmmm.  Still doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to output?  What is the plain english version of what you want to see on the screen, not necessarily what you want to do in code?

Comment: I want to have four sets of data, `name, followers, imageurl and rank` I want to have a `rank` value based on the amount of `followers` in descending order, so an entry in `followers` with the highest numeric value will get assigned rank 1, all the way down to the lowest at rank 15. I want to then put these sets of data into a MySQL database with the columns name, followers, url, rank so that they can be selected and week on week rank AND follower changes can be shown. The last part isn't a problem, but the first is.

Comment: It would be nice just to sort the `$followers` array then `array_flip` to get ranks, however because all the keys and values in the 3 arrays `$name, $followers and $imageurl` are relative, I can't.